# Erlang socket doesn't receive until the second setopts {active,once}

Tags: tcp, erlang

First I would like to apologize, I'm giving so much information to make it as clear as possible what the problem is. Please let me know if there's still anything which needs clarifying.

(Running erlang R13B04, kernel 2.6.18-194, centos 5.5)

I have a very strange problem. I have the following code to listen and process sockets:

```
%Opts used to make listen socket
-define(TCP_OPTS, [binary, {packet, raw}, {nodelay, true}, {reuseaddr, true}, {active, false},{keepalive,true}]).

%Acceptor loop which spawns off sock processors when connections
%come in
accept_loop(Listen) ->
    case gen_tcp:accept(Listen) of
    {ok, Socket} ->
        Pid = spawn(fun()->?MODULE:process_sock(Socket) end),
        gen_tcp:controlling_process(Socket,Pid);
    {error,_} -> do_nothing
    end,
    ?MODULE:accept_loop(Listen).

%Probably not relevant
process_sock(Sock) ->
    case inet:peername(Sock) of
    {ok,{Ip,_Port}} -> 
        case Ip of
        {172,16,_,_} -> Auth = true;
        _ -> Auth = lists:member(Ip,?PUB_IPS)
        end,
        ?MODULE:process_sock_loop(Sock,Auth);
    _ -> gen_tcp:close(Sock)
    end.

process_sock_loop(Sock,Auth) ->
    try inet:setopts(Sock,[{active,once}]) of
    ok ->
        receive
        {tcp_closed,_} -> 
            ?MODULE:prepare_for_death(Sock,[]);
        {tcp_error,_,etimedout} -> 
            ?MODULE:prepare_for_death(Sock,[]);

        %Not getting here
        {tcp,Sock,Data} ->
            ?MODULE:do_stuff(Sock,Data);

        _ ->
            ?MODULE:process_sock_loop(Sock,Auth)
        after 60000 ->
            ?MODULE:process_sock_loop(Sock,Auth)
        end;
    {error,_} ->
        ?MODULE:prepare_for_death(Sock,[]) 
    catch _:_ -> 
        ?MODULE:prepare_for_death(Sock,[])
    end.
```

This whole setup works wonderfully normally, and has been working for the past few months. The server operates as a message passing server with long-held tcp connections, and it holds on average about 100k connections. However now we're trying to use the server more heavily. We're making two long-held connections (in the future probably more) to the erlang server and making a few hundred commands every second per each of those connections. Each of those commands, in the common case, spawn off a new thread which will probably make some kind of read from mnesia, and send some messages based on that.

The strangeness comes when we try to test those two command connections. When we turn on the stream of commands, any new connection has about 50% chance of hanging. For instance, using netcat if I were to connect and send along the string "blahblahblah" the server should immediately return back an error. In doing this it won't make any calls outside the thread (since all it's doing is trying to parse the command, which will fail because blahblahblah isn't a command). But about 50% of the time (when the two command connections are running) typing in blahblahblah results in the server just sitting there for 60 seconds before returning that error.

In trying to debug this I pulled up wireshark. The tcp handshake always happens immediately, and when the first packet from the client (netcat) is sent it acks immediately, telling me that the tcp stack of the kernel isn't the bottleneck. My only guess is that the problem lies in the process_sock_loop function. It has a receive which will go back to the top of the function after 60 seconds and try again to get more from the socket. My best guess is that the following is happening:

- Connection is made, thread moves on to process_sock_loop
- {active,once} is set
- Thread receives, **but doesn't get data even though it's there**
- After 60 seconds thread goes back to the top of process_sock_loop
- {active, once} is set again
- This time the data comes through, things proceed as normal

Why this would be I have no idea, and when we turn those two command connections off everything goes back to normal and the problem goes away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's likely that your first call to set {active,once} is failing due to a race condition between your call to spawn and your call to controlling_process

it will be intermittent, likely based on host load.

When doing this, I'd normally spawn a function that blocks on something like:
{take,Sock}

and then call your loop on the sock, setting {active,once}.

so you'd change the acceptor to spawn, set controlling_process then Pid ! {take,Sock}

something to that effect.
note: I don't know if the {active,once} call actually throws when you aren't the controlling processes, if it doesn't, then what I just said makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ended up trying to upgrade my version of erlang to R14, and in the process upgraded to CentOS 6 as well, and the problem hasn't showed up again after that. It's possible that the only reason the problem went away is due to the new release having less load on the cpu, and once it picks up some more it will show up again, but I haven't been able to make it happen again.

Comment: Turns out upgrading didn't completely fix the issue. Adding in this little fix did, however. Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone checks this answer, [ERL-90](http://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-90) contains more information on the actual cause of this hang.